# Tapestry : Access page/component property in corresponding javascript file

Tags: javascript, tapestry

Let's say I have a component called testComp which has a string property testProperty. Corresponding to testComp.java, is a js file testComp.js

How can I access testProp in testComp.js?

I tried following but it is giving an error.

```
console.log( ${testProp} );
```

I know I can do ${testProp} in tml file but I need to access this property in javascript file. I have searched in mailing list but no luck so far. Any idea how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

testComp.java

```
@Inject
private JavaScriptSupport javaScriptSupport;

@AfterRender
private void after() throws Exception {
    JSONObject arguments = new JSONObject();
    arguments.put("testProperty", this.testProperty);
    javaScriptSupport.addInitializerCall("testComp", arguments);
}
```

testComp.js

```
Tapestry.Initializer.testComp = function (json) {
    new testComp(json);
};


function testComp(json){
    alert(json.testProperty);
}
```